# Getting multiselect dropdown value in php using chosen

Tags: php, jquery

i am using chosen for my select dropdown. what i want is when i post data save it in an array to post data to database,

Problem is that when i post data it gets only one  value instead of multiple values. I tried using gettype and posted value is a string not an array

Below is the code

```
<select id="tableset"  multiple="multiple"  class="form-control select2 table_id" name="table_id[]">
  <option value="">Table</option>
  <?php foreach ($tables as $tbls) { ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $tbls->id; ?>"><?php echo $tbls->name; ?></option>
  <?php } ?>
</select>
```

**php code**

```
  foreach ($_GET['table_id'] as $selectedOption){
         echo $selectedOption;
     }
```

this prints last item selected , can you help me to specifiy whats wrong here

Comment: How can you select several options on a non-multiple select?

Comment: i added that still not working

Comment: Are you selecting multiple values? How did you even test that before you added the `multiple` attribute?

Comment: yes here is screenshot https://ibb.co/cMzjK9

Comment: Can you `print_r($_GET['table_id'])`? No reason why this should happen, using chosen or not.

Comment: Are you sure there's no another form element with same name table_id?

Answer (score 0):

If you wouldn't mind, you can try these.

```
function SelectedValues(){
    var result=[] 
    $("#table_id:selected").each(function(){
       result.push($(this).val();
    });
    return result
  }

function functionForSendingAjax(){
    var option = SelectedValues();
    jsondata = json.stringify({"data":option});
    ajax({
      data:jsondata;
      //url:
      //success:
    });
   }
```